# Connect to a WIFI network through terminal

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, terminal, wireless-adapter

I have several WIFI USB adapters connected to my Macbook, I'd like to connect each one of them to a different WIFI network.

Which terminal commands would be useful in my case?

Comment: You have this tagged as both Linux and macOS. Which OS are you running on your MacBook hardware? macOS's command-line environment is based on BSD Unix, not Linux, so the commands and command options are often different in macOS than Linux, even though they are both Unix-like OSes at the surface.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I am running macOS.

Answer (score 0):

To associate a connection via cli:

```
# create an alias for ease of use
alias airport='/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport'
# list the available SSIDs
airport -s
# list the available hardware
networksetup -listallhardwareports
# join a specific network, on a specific interface:
networksetup -setairportnetwork en3 AWiFiNet AWiFiPassword
```

Also `man networksetup` and `airport -h` for further usage.

- note: <strike>untested</strike> does not work with multiple NICs

Comment: Have you actually used these commands on a macOS system with multiple Wi-Fi adapters to make different adapters join different networks, concurrently? If not, you may want to edit your Answer to say so. I'm under the impression that macOS's Wi-Fi software subsystems don't actually have support for multiple concurrent active Wi-Fi NICs.

Comment: I think you can use multiple NICs, driver dependent. You will definitely have to manually setup your routes - as macos gives the default route to the nic with highest priority, but routing seems beyond the scope of the question, which was specific to OSI-layer1: interfaces and SSIDs. Layer3 is an exercise for the reader. See `man route` and `man ifconfig`.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.

I was only able to connect one of the USB WIFI adapters, for the others I am being displayed with this error:

"en9 is not a Wi-Fi interface.
** Error: Error obtaining wireless information".

In System Preferences > Network
There's only one 802.11n NIC active.

Comment: Sorry. Added edits to indicate it didn't work.